# Add documentation of attributes generated on runtime using Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, getattr

My class implements a `__getattr__` method that, for a limited number of accepted keys, returns valid data. I would like to add the docstring documentation inside the class for these few keys so that they are listed exactly as the standard properties (marked with `@property` decorator), i.e. providing a short description in the "Attributes Summary" section and the full documentation in "Attributes Documentation" section of the generated HTML output.

Is it possible? I tried the "Attributes" keyword, but the resulting documentation is separated from the rest.

Short example for visualisation of my problem:

```
class Example(object):
    """Some documentation of the class
    
    Attributes
    ----------
    bb
        Documentation of "bb"
    """

    @property
    def aa(self):
        """Documentation of "aa" """
        pass

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if key == "bb":  # valid key emulating a property
            pass
```

The resulting documentation looks like that:

[image: Resulting doxygen output]

Thanks!

Comment: Please expand the example into a proper [mcve]. What exactly gets separated from "the rest"?

Comment: Done. I added the documentation with the "Attributes" key and the resulting doxygen output page.

Comment: How is Doxygen involved? Are you using Breathe (https://breathe.readthedocs.io)?

Comment: Sorry. We don't use doxygen. The documentation is built using the sphinx builder "python -msphinx"

Comment: Sorry, but you have still not provided a real [mcve]. It looks like you might be using the `automodapi` extension. It generates just those "Attributes Summary" and "Attributes Documentation" headings.

Comment: Yes, you're right. We actually use this extension. I did some more research, but still don't know, how to add those attributes. Should I rather try to include them in the *.rst file? There is one for each module, containing only `.. automodapi::` and `:members:` directives